# Converting character inputs into numerical variables

Tags: java

Consider the following input as an example:

`User_Input> x`

which is read from the following code:

```
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Is it possible to declare a numerical variable which has the same name of the string read?

Comment: sounds like you want to use a Map<String, Integer>.

Comment: Unclear; what is your real question? Provide sample inputs and expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert the string to an integer, use the Integer.parseInt() method.

For long types, Long.parseLong().  And so on.

Comment: ... and of course don't forget to catch `NumberFormatException` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
String s = scan.nextLine();

int i;

try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // Handle problem
}
```